# LLVM bitcode cross-platform

Tags: c++, cross-platform, llvm

Just to be sure: Is LLVM bitcode cross-platform? By which I mean, can the generated IR (".bc") file be distrubuted and interpreted/JITed over various platforms?

If so, how does Clang convert C++ into platform independend code? While in the C++ language itself, preprocessors for determining it's target platform are used before it actually compiles.

Comment: If the object is entirely self-contained, it could be interpreted on a different platform. But since the ABI will be different, it will have a hard time using the rest of the system.

Comment: I assume that http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html would be completly platform independend. What do you mean exactly by 'hart time using the rest of the system'?

Comment: @Tim - Will the code use any OS calls? How portable are they?

Comment: @BoPersson Well the C++ standard library uses OS calls I assume.

Comment: This sounds like Google's PNaCl project, which uses LLVM bitcode as architecture-independent Native Client executables, the idea being to distribute (untrusted) bitcode, JIT it, and run it inside a web browser regardless of processor type. [The PNaCl paper](http://nativeclient.googlecode.com/svn/data/site/pnacl.pdf) explains many of the issues involved. You might also be interested in the specifics of their [bitcode ABI](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/bitcode-abi).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

LLVM IR can be cross-platform, with the obvious exceptions others have listed. However, that does not mean Clang generates cross-platform code. As you note, the preprocessor is almost universally used to only pass parts of the code to the C/C++ compiler, depending on the platform. Even when this is not done in user code, many system headers include a bit or two that's platform-specific, such as `typedef`s. For example, if you compile C code using `size_t` to LLVM IR on a platform where `size_t` is 32 bit, the LLVM IR now uses `i32` for that, and there's no way in hell you can reverse engineer that to fix it.

Google's [Portable Native Client](http://nativeclient.googlecode.com/svn/data/site/pnacl.pdf) project (thanks @willglynn for the link), if I understand it correctly, achieves portability by fixing the ABI for all target platforms. So in that sense, it doesn't solve the aforementioned issues: The LLVM IR is not portable to platform with a different ABI. The only reason this is more portable is that the clients provide a layer which matches the PNaCl ABI to the actual ABI. In other words, PNaCl code isn't portable to many platforms, the "PNaCl VM" is.

So, bottom line: If you're very careful, you can use LLVM IR across multiple platforms, but not without doing significant additional work (which Clang doesn't do) to abstract over the ABI differences.

Comment: Portable Native Client's link returns 404.

Comment: See more about Google's Native Client [here](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/34913.pdf)

Comment: @JohnDoe Late to the party, but the technology has been removed from Chrome nowadays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client

Answer (score 12):

**Given an IR file, can I be sure it could compile to my target?**

You can *not* assume an arbitrary IR file will always be cross-platform, as there are things in a given file that might not be platform-independent. The most notable example is that the IR can contain actual assembler sequences (via [module-level](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#moduleasm) or [inline](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#inline-assembler-expressions) assembly segments), but there are other examples - e.g. usage of target specific intrinsics or calling conventions that are only supported on some targets.

**Can I generate an IR file that is guaranteed to compile on all targets?**

I don't know, but I believe you can, especially if you avoid specifying things like inline assembly, calling conventions, required / preferred ABI for types, etc. It can affect the optimizations the compiler will perform, though.