# Compiling Boost as LLVM bitcode

Tags: boost, clang, llvm

First of all, I am only doing something for fun, not for production.

LLVM's bitcode, to some extents, can works like Java's bytecode that can be cross platform. I think it should works in most situations, unless your code consists of some inline asm or something special. I have successfully compiled a simple hello world program with `clang` to LLVM bitcode in Linux, and run it properly with `lli` in Windows.

But, how can I use boost library such as boost_thread in that way? I can pack bitcode files together with `llvm-link`, and it will still be cross platform. But if I link the bitcode with *.a by some methods (I have not tried to do that, but it seems that I can do so even `llvm-ld` has been removed), it will probably not be cross platform anymore (and become a native binary executable file). So, I want to compile boost to LLVM bitcode, so that I can link the boost library to my program.

If you think that linking it statically will make the bitcode to large, you can also 'link' them in runtime, by `lli <your bitcode> <boost's bitcode>...`

I have compiled boost with `./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-emit-llvm -c"`. I am not sure whether I am in the right way. If not, is there any way for me to compile boost to bitcodes?

EDIT:
The above command *seems* to be partially work. The *.o files produced are LLVM bitcode, but it will then be archived to *.a. Simply decompress the *.a and use `llvm-link` to link the files in the archive together may work.

*BUT*, unfortunately, there is inline asm in boost's thread library. So, it cannot run...

Comment: Your assumption that LLVM can be cross-platform is technically correct but misleading. There is *much* more than inline asm  in `clang -emit-llvm` output than makes it platform-specific, see [LLVM bitcode cross-platform](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14258194/395760).

Comment: Yes, after further studies, I found that making LLVM bitcode cross-platform is practically not achievable.